# Optimizing 150 lines of codes for something simple

Tags: c#

I need help with optimizing a piece of code I've written in C#. It is very sloppy right now. I needed to write a code that tracks the amount of money a hospital made at the of the day depending on the amount of patients. Here are some conditions and details :

- Code has to display the cost for the patient AND the amount of money made at the end of the day

[image]

- When a radio image and a consultation is done in one time by the same patient, there is a 25% price reduction off the price of a radio image.
- When a patient does a consultation, a blood check and an injection. That person gets 10$ AFTER paying tax.
- The injections can be either 30ml, 50ml or 60ml. The prices are proportionate to the quantity of product injected. (Eg : Someone aged 20 that takes a 50ml shot has to pay 25$)
- Taxes are 15%

========

Here's the code I've written for the problem.

```
        int client;
        int clientfinal = 0;
        double injprix = 0;
        double consprix = 0;
        double imgradprix = 0;
        double analyzeprix = 0;
        double prixtot = 0;
        double prixclient = 0;
        double prixfinal = 0;

        int injtaille = 0;
        string cons, inj, imgrad, analyze;
        Console.WriteLine("Combien a t-il de client aujourd'hui?");
        client = (Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));

        if (client > 0)

                do //un client
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Quel est l'age du patient?");
                    client = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (client < 12)
                    {
                        client = 1;
                    }
                    if (client >= 12 || client <= 18)
                    {
                        client = 2;
                    }
                    if (client >= 19 || client <= 65)
                    {
                        client = 3;
                    }
                    if (client > 65)
                    {
                        client = 4;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("La personne a t-elle choisit une consultation?");
                    cons = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine()).ToLower();
                    Console.WriteLine("La personne a t-elle choisit une image radio?");
                    imgrad = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine()).ToLower();
                    Console.WriteLine("La personne a t-elle choisit une analyze de sang?");
                    analyze = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine()).ToLower();
                    Console.WriteLine("La personne a t-elle choisit une injection?");
                    inj = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine()).ToLower();
                    if (inj == "oui")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Quel est la taille de l'injection? (30 - 50 - 60) ");
                        injtaille = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                    switch (client)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            consprix = 25;
                            imgradprix = 55;
                            analyzeprix = 28;
                            injprix = 0;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            consprix = 32;
                            imgradprix = 65;
                            analyzeprix = 32;
                            switch (injtaille)
                            {
                                case 30:
                                    injprix = 13;
                                    break;
                                case 50:
                                    injprix = (650 / 30);
                                    break;
                                case 60:
                                    injprix = (780 / 30);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    Console.WriteLine("Taille d'injection inconnue.");
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            consprix = 40;
                            imgradprix = 70;
                            analyzeprix = 40;
                            switch (injtaille)
                            {
                                case 30:
                                    injprix = 13;
                                    break;
                                case 50:
                                    injprix = (750 / 30);
                                    break;
                                case 60:
                                    injprix = (900 / 30);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    Console.WriteLine("Taille d'injection inconnue.");
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;

                        case 4:
                            consprix = 30;
                            imgradprix = 60;
                            analyzeprix = 35;
                            switch (injtaille)
                            {
                                case 30:
                                    injprix = 13;
                                    break;
                                case 50:
                                    injprix = (600 / 30);
                                    break;
                                case 60:
                                    injprix = (720 / 30);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    Console.WriteLine("Taille d'injection inconnue.");
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                 //Fin Switch


                    if (imgrad == "non")
                {
                    imgradprix = 0;
                }
                    if (cons == "non")
                {
                    consprix = 0;
                }
                    if (analyze == "non")
                {
                    analyzeprix = 0;
                }
                    if (inj == "non")
                {
                    injprix = 0;
                }
                    if (imgrad == "oui" || cons == "oui")
                    {
                        imgradprix = imgradprix * 0.75;
                    }

                    prixclient = consprix + imgradprix + analyzeprix + injprix;
                    prixclient = prixclient * 1.15;
                    if (cons == "oui" || analyze == "oui" || inj == "oui")
                    {
                        prixclient = prixclient - 10;
                    }
                    prixtot += prixclient;
                    clientfinal++;
                    prixfinal = prixtot;
                Console.WriteLine("Prix du patient " + prixclient);
                } while (clientfinal != client);
        Console.WriteLine("Le prix final est" + prixfinal);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please excuse my lack of knowlege in programming and sloppy english.

Comment: this question is probably better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I've posted one there too.

Comment: The trick here is goign to be getting rid all this switching and iffing by creating a client object upfront so that you can forget about the age differences.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code the only problem I see is you have a memory leak because you are allocating an event handler and never de allocating it.

```
prixtot += prixclient;
```

I would suggest using visual studio 2015. It has a profiling tool out of the box that will  give you insights into issues with your code. You can see how long the function takes to execute etc.

Andrew Hall videos on MSDN's and Microsoft build are a great place to start.
Here are a few links videos to watch

https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-677
https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-731